# How can I retrieve multilple JSON files with Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

Hi im having issue trying to figure out how to call multiple json files on my local folder, im only able to read one...need help please

```js
class App {

    getIdInHash = (slug) => {
        let hash = location.hash,
            hashInArray = hash.split(`#!/${slug}/`),
            id = hashInArray[1];

        return id;
    }

    afficherDetail = (id) => {
        console.log('AfficherDetail');

        fetch('data.json')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {

                console.log(data);
                //On va chercher la div vide
                let elResult = document.querySelector('[data-js-result]');
                //On injecte le resultat
                elResult.innerHTML = `<p>Les cépages de la région ${data[id].region ? data[id].region : '' } sont : ${data[id].cepage}.</p>`;;
            
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(`Il y a eu un problème avec l'opération fetch: ${error.message}`);
            });
    };
}

export const { getIdInHash, afficherDetail } = new App();
```

Comment: You cannot fetch files from the clients file system

Comment: Have you tried calling `fetch` for each file?

Comment: Use `Promise.all()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff sure you can it works with one file

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to read multiple files is to have an array with filenames

```
var promisList = [];
var resultList = [];
var fileNameList = ['data1.json', 'data2.json', 'data3.json'];

fileNameList.forEach((fileName, index) => {
  promiseList.push(
    fetch(fileName).then(response => {
      resultList[index] = response.json();
    })
  );
});

// since all is async, we need to wait all promises to be finished
Promise
  .all(promiseList)
  .then(() => {
    // all promises finished
    // all results saved in resultList
    // put your logic here
  });
```

Comment: ill give it a try